# Add a root element name using JMS Serializer with Symfony 2.6

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer, symfony-2.6

I have implemented web services using `Symfony 2.6` with `FOSRestBundle` and `JMSSerializerBundle`.

I can't manage to have a root element named `request` eventhough I put `xml_root_name: request` in the configuration file.

I have a `config\serializer\Entity.Request.yml` file with the following information:

```
Tvjp\RequestBundle\Entity\Request:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    xml_root_name: request
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
            type: integer
        label:
            expose: true
            type: string
        issuer:
            expose: true
            type: string
```

When I try to access to a single `request`, this is what I get in XML :

```
<result>
    <id>23</id>
    <label><![CDATA[ test label ws post ]]></label>
    <issuer><![CDATA[ test issuer ws post ]]></issuer>
</result>
```

And what I get in json : `{"id":23,"label":"test label ws post","issuer":"test issuer ws post"}`

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Did you run `cache:clear` after each modification ?

Comment: Yes. I have clear the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to make it work using annotations on the entity class instead of using the `config\serializer\Entity.Request.yml`file.

So i deleted the file `config\serializer\Entity.Request.yml` and here is my entity `Request` file :

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy,
    JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose,
    JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type,
    JMS\Serializer\Annotation\XmlRoot;

/**
 * Request
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @XmlRoot("request") 
 */
class Request{

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Expose
     * @Type("integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Expose
     * @Type("string")
     */
    private $label;

   /**
    * @var string
    * @Expose
    * @Type("string")
    */
    private $issuer;

    [...]
}
```